# HTML Form , Select only one radio button out of three radio sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a HTML form we have three radio button sets for three classes, for example

```
Class 1
<input id="Level1" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
Class 2
<input id="Level1" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
Class 3
<input id="Level1" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
<input id="Level4" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level4" />Level 4<br>
```

At this time, user can select ONE from each of the radio set. We want them to select only ONE radio button, from all of them. Its mean, user can select only one level out of three classes.

Please suggest something, may be in Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Then give a same name to all of those 3 set of radio buttons

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy We can't give the same name to all of them, as we want to track the class selection too.

Comment: you can track the selection by id

Comment: Btw you should never use same `id` attribute on multiple html elements

Comment: according to your question answer is correct

Comment: i agree with  Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy ,you can get current selected radio button value  and use for your track  and  for this you give same class to all radio button and get value or id or other attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"].classOnly').on('change', function(){
    $('input[type="radio"].classOnly:checked').not(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Class 1
<input id="Level1" name="Classl" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Classl" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Classl" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
Class 2
<input id="Level1" name="Class2" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Class2" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Class2" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
Class 3
<input id="Level1" name="Class3" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level1" />Level 1<br>
<input id="Level2" name="Class3" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level2" />Level 2<br>
<input id="Level3" name="Class3" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level3" />Level 3<br>
<input id="Level4" name="Class3" type="radio" class="classOnly" value="Level4" />Level 4<br>
```

Comment: thanks you for the code, it is a long form, we only make this restriction for these 3 radio sets. not for all.

Comment: updated answer as per apply to a group by class attribute `classOnly`;

Answer (score 3):

> We can't give the same name to all of them, as we want to track the class selection too

Then the class selection should be part of the value.

```
<label>
  <input id="Level1" name="Class" type="radio" value="Classl-Level1" />
  Level 1
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
i would recommend not using same id multiple times, use class instead.

```js
$('.radioCollection').find('input:radio').on('click', function() {

  $('.radioCollection').find('input:radio').not($(this)).attr('checked', false);

  //you can remove below code

  var mainId = $(this).closest('.radioCollection').attr('id'); // class1 || class2 || class3

  var log = '';
  if ($(this).hasClass('Level1')) {
    //Level1
    log = 'Level1';

  } else if ($(this).hasClass('Level2')) {
    //Level2
    log = 'Level2';
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('Level3')) {
    //Level3
    log = 'Level3';
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('Level4')) {
    //Level4
    log = 'Level4';
  }

  $('.tempLog')
    .html('Selected Main Class: <span>' + mainId + '</span><br/> Selected Radio Class: <span>' + log + '</span>');
})
```

```css
.tempLog {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #888;
}
.tempLog span {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 800;
}
input:radio {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tempLog"></div>

Class 1
<div id="class1" class="radioCollection">
  <input class="Level1" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1
  <br>
  <input class="Level2" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2
  <br>
  <input class="Level3" name="Classl" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3
  <br>
</div>
Class 2
<div id="class2" class="radioCollection">
  <input class="Level1" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1
  <br>
  <input class="Level2" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2
  <br>
  <input class="Level3" name="Class2" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3
</div>
<br>Class 3

<div id="class3" class="radioCollection">
  <input class="Level1" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level1" />Level 1
  <br>
  <input class="Level2" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level2" />Level 2
  <br>
  <input class="Level3" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level3" />Level 3
  <br>
  <input class="Level4" name="Class3" type="radio" value="Level4" />Level 4</div>
<br>
```

Hope this helps..:)